# Cannot cluster WSO2 API manager 2.6.0 using Hazelcast

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, wso2-api-manager

I am working on Hazelcast clustering WSO2 API Manager (following doc: [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Working+with+Hazelcast+Clustering#WorkingwithHazelcastClustering-EnablingHazelcastclustering)](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Working+with+Hazelcast+Clustering#WorkingwithHazelcastClustering-EnablingHazelcastclustering) Here I have two nodes under the same domain 127.0.0.1.

Let us assume A is running in port 4001 while B is running in port 4002. I have joined the two nodes as

A -

```
     <members>
        <member>
            <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
            <port>4002</port>
        </member>
        <member>
            <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
            <port>4001</port>
        </member>
    </members>
```

B -

```
        <members>
            <member>
                <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
                <port>4001</port>
            </member>
            <member>
                <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
                <port>4001</port>
            </member>
        </members>
```

I also tried as;

A -

```
 <members>
    <member>
        <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
        <port>4002</port>
    </member>
</members>
```

B -

```
<members>
    <member>
        <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
        <port>4002</port>
    </member>
</members>
```

But both methods returned as below

```
2019-11-27 13:23:16,763]  INFO - SocketAcceptor [127.0.0.1]:0 [wso2.am.domain] [3.5.4] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:51206
[2019-11-27 13:23:16,763]  INFO - TcpIpConnectionManager [127.0.0.1]:0 [wso2.am.domain] [3.5.4] Established socket connection between /127.0.0.1:4001
[2019-11-27 13:23:16,764]  WARN - TcpIpConnectionManager [127.0.0.1]:0 [wso2.am.domain] [3.5.4] Wrong bind request from Address[127.0.0.1]:0! This node is not requested endpoint: Address[127.0.0.1]:4001
[2019-11-27 13:23:16,764]  INFO - TcpIpConnection [127.0.0.1]:0 [wso2.am.domain] [3.5.4] Connection [/127.0.0.1:51206] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
[2019-11-27 13:23:44,354]  INFO - TcpIpConnectionManager [127.0.0.1]:0 [wso2.am.domain] [3.5.4] Established socket connection between /127.0.0.1:51211
[2019-11-27 13:23:44,359]  INFO - TcpIpConnection [127.0.0.1]:0 [wso2.am.domain] [3.5.4] Connection [Address[127.0.0.1]:4002] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
[2019-11-27 13:23:44,360]  WARN - ReadHandler [127.0.0.1]:0 [wso2.am.domain] [3.5.4] hz.wso2.am.domain.instance.IO.thread-in-1 Closing socket to endpoint Address[127.0.0.1]:4002, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need hazelcast clustering?

Comment: Because it is the task

Comment: Using hazelcast is not recommended anymore. That's why I asked why you need it. What is it for?

Comment: It was a task to do. Found the answer

Comment: @Bee `hazelcast is not recommended anymore` - could you give us a hint what shall we use for clustering? (I found clustering useful for coordinating the scheduled tasks and messaging processors)

Comment: There are only 2 cases you need hazelcast for. This docs discusses those 2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Working+with+Hazelcast+Clustering

In APIM 3.0, even immediate token revocation does not require hazelcast. it happens through a pub-sub model.

Comment: Please note my statement is regarding APIM only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Issue solved]

The answer is "*Use local machine IP instead of localhost* ". There are **02** options.

#### Option 01

Add the following to the `tasks/main.yml`

```
# Get local IP
- name: get local ip
  debug:
    var: ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

and this to site.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
```

#### Option 02

Add the following snippet to site.yml

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - carbon
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
```